# How do you display google sheet data in Adobe Animate?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, flash, air, adobe-animate

Just a quick one. Someone I know is using google sheets as a Read database. Their data needs are very small so that's what they want to use. I have built an App in Adobe Air and this person wants to be able to display the sheet data inside this app. I know I am going to be using some form of Javascript to do this but I am not sure how to pull the cell data into the dynamic text fields. Any advice would be most welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

**Way №1**. The *simplest* way is to get the cell data as a **CSV** or **TSV** file (whatever is more suitable for your purposes) via special download link: [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/**{KEY}**/export?gid=**{GID}**&format=csv](http://docs.google.com/)

Obviously, you are to replace **{KEY}** and **{GID}** with valid document key and sheet identifier respectively. The **format** parameter takes **csv** or **tsv** value.

You read it with old good **URLLoader** and get a plain text which you split into lines and then every line into values. There shouldn't be any problems.

**IMPORTANT**: The document should be shared as "*anyone with link*", so there are apparent security concerns, yet if security is not an issue, go for it as it is, as I said above, the *simplest* way.

**Way №2**. If security **IS** a concern, then you need to use the **gspread** library. It does not have an **AS3** port, but it has **JS** one so I assume it is the one that acquaintance of yours uses: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js

You don't run your app in the browser, **JS** wouldn't really be your ally here, you will need a server with **PHP** proxy (that will handle auth and communication with **Google Sheets**) or a local **Python** app maybe (it is not difficult to build and run a simple **HTTP** serving application), it is up to you to decide which one of the available **gspread** ports will be simpler for you to use and serves your needs best.

Comment: You are a legend! Thanks man.